# Why can't send queue message text to an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App with a queue trigger. The queue message is JSON. When I send "Message text" to an Azure function, I get

```
UnsupportedMediaType
{
  "Message": "The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON."
}
```

I'd assumed this would work directly.I tried setting request body to

```
@{json(<Message text>)}
```

where  is the select dynamic content item, but I get red message "Enter a valid json".

What's the trick to making this connection? Do I have to pass in  and then parse out "Message text" in my function? Again, I assumed it would do that automagically.

Comment: Also, why are there two dynamic elements named "Body" coming from the message queue trigger?

Comment: Can you confirm that they are both coming from the trigger? You would see one for any preceding action as well. It could also be the case that there is a property named 'body' in the content, hence the designer would show one token for message content as w whole, and one for the property named 'body'. Which specific queue trigger are you using?

Comment: I have a "when there are messages in the queue" trigger. Immediately after I have a Function action. The dynamic content list has two "Body" entries. 
http://shufflepoint-media.s3.amazonaws.com/double_body.png

Comment: I ended up passing the body into my function, and then parsing the "message text". That works, but like I said, I would have assumed that I could pass in "message text" directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `@{}` syntax indicates string interpolation. This means that your expression `@{json(<Message text>)}` de-serializes the message text to json, and then serializes it again.

Hence the expression that you want to use is

```
@json(<Message text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

I was passing some (what seems to be to be valid) json to my webhook.

And kept getting the

**"Message": "The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON."**

error.

:(

Finally, I found a json "expression" that did its voodoo and got rid of the error.  I argument from the json-expression was my previous action's output, which was valid json.  It apparently needs just a little help!

[image]

The raw (non designer) code was:

```
        "GenericWebHookCsharpOne": {
          "type": "Function",
          "inputs": {
            "body": "@json( body('MyPreviousAppLogicActionWhichIsAnAzureFunction'))",
            "method": "POST",
            "function": {
              "id": "/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            }
```

Comment: I know this is kinda like Szymon's answer.  So I'm not trying to take away from his.  Just adding for everyone mutual benefit.